# Placing equation numbers on the right

Tags: equations, numbering, positioning

I am new to TeX and am using [scribtex](http://scribtex.com) to write a maths paper. When I put the followng code, the equation number is automatically displayed on the left, instead of in the right as is usually done. What is the problem and how do I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Let us consider a spherical symmetric metric in curvature coordinates:
\begin{equation} 
\label{metric}
ds^2=-e^\lambda dr^2-r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2)+e^\nu dt^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}​
```

The output I get is

[image: output]

Comment: "What is the problem ..." Hmmm! Aren't you the one to tell us?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add the `reqno` document class option to your current file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,reqno]{amsart}
```

[image]

This will override the default left equation numbering scheme of the [`amsart` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/amscls). The following, taken from the [AMS document class documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsclass.pdf) provides some background (p 7):

> **Equation numbering on the left or right**
>
> The option `leqno` - equation numbers on the left - is the default in
>   AMS styles. Therefore we provide also a `reqno` option.

Comment: `leqno` and `reqno` are options of all document classes. I think your answer is too localized to `amsart`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I don't read the answer as implying that the `leqno` applies *only* to the `amsart` package; the answer was merely taking the OP's specific example and showed how to add the required option.

Comment: @Mico: The answer is correct. My sentence based on the part *default left equation numbering scheme of the amsart*

Comment: Assume one has put leqno in the preample. Can one change the position to the right locally in one equation?

Comment: @Mappi: Yes. See [Switch between `leqno` and `reqno` options (of `amsmath`) in the same document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193535/5764).