# Move \tag to right side of line in align* environment

Tags: numbering, amsart, tags

I am currently trying to label an line in an align* environment using `\tag`; however, the tag appears on the left side of the line instead of on the right. How do I move this label to the right side?

Thank you!

```
 %latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    We begin by formulating the profit maximization problem and taking the first order condition.
    \begin{align*}
        \max_q \left(pq-C(q)\right) \\
        \max_q \left(pq-10q-q^2 \right) \\
        \frac{\partial \pi}{\partial q}=p-10-2q=0 \tag{First-Order Condition}
    \end{align*}
    We then formulate market balance by substituting $nq$ in for $Q$.
    \begin{align*}
        p=100-6Q \\
        p=100-6nq \tag{Market Balance}
    \end{align*}
    Lastly, we write the expression for profits for a firm and set this equal to zero.
    \begin{align*}
        pq-C(q)=0 \\
        (100-6nq)q-10q-q^2=0 \tag{Equilibrium Entry}
    \end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end document
```

[image: Tag on left]

Comment: Do you want this only for these `\tag`s, or for all equation numbers? If the latter, add `reqno` to the class options, see [Placing equation numbers on the right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32753)

Comment: Off-topic, but maybe still of relevance: None of the three `align` environments in your example contain a single alignment point; as a result, the three equation groups are all right-aligned. Is this deliberate?

Comment: I was intending to align them on the equals signs. Sorry about that. I do not want equation numbers, however, I want to give them text names.

Comment: No, my point was that if you have numbered equations somewhere else in your document, then `reqno` will move their numbers to the right as well. Is that what you want, or do you want *just these three `\tag`s* moved to the right?

Comment: I do not have numbered equations elsewhere. `reqno` worked perfectly. Thank you.