# Numbering Equations in the following form

Tags: equations, numbering, lyx

I would like to number equations (in increasing order using positive integers) so that the number appears in parenthses (n) in the right margin. Currently, my equation numbers appear in the left margin and the number corresponding to the nth equation in section m is (m.n). How can I edit the numbers and the location?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[english]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\section{\textbf{Introduction.}}

\begin{doublespace}
\begin{equation}
A=B
\end{equation}
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want the equation numbers be simple integers that are incremented consecutively, get rid of the `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` statement.

Comment: Document > Settings... > Document Class > Class options > Custom: `reqno`; Document > Settings... > Modules > Selected > Number Equations by Section (Delete).

Comment: @Werner, Indeed. I had no idea that was in my selection box. Must be a default.

Comment: Yes. If you find the marked question not a duplicate, then you can view to reopen and I can write a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

To have the numbering on the right, you have to replace
`\documentclass[english]{amsart}`
by
`\documentclass[english,reqno]{amsart}`
(See [Placing equation numbers on the right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32751/placing-equation-numbers-on-the-right))

Edit : and like @Mico said, juste comment your `numberwithin` commands

Comment: I am using LyX and don't know how to replace `\documentclass[english]{amsart}`. When I include `\documentclass[english,reqno]{amsart}` into my source code LyX says there's a error ("the document may only declare one class").

Comment: Nevermind. Werner's comment resolves the issue.